# Select last child preceded by all elements with the same attribute

Tags: css

I was wondering if there is a way to select the last element chid that is preceded by all elements with the same attribute, using CSS.

Example:

```html
<div>
    <div data-myattr></div>
    <div data-myattr></div>
    <div data-myattr></div>
    <div></div>  <!-- I want to select and style this element -->
</div>

<div>
    <div data-myattr></div>
    <div></div>
    <div data-myattr></div>
    <div></div>  <!-- I don't want to select and style this element -->
</div>
```

**The number of divs is variable.**

I guess not, but I preferred to ask.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd have to use javascript

Comment: Is there always 3 (or another number but always known) divs with a possible `data-myattr` attribute ? Is this attribute always `data-myattr` or it can be another one ? Are you willing to use JS ?

Comment: @CedricCholley the number of divs is variable. I can use JS but It would be better using CSS only

Comment: @fabruex If the number of divs is "reasonable" you could use ΔO 'deltazero' answer with all the possibilities. I guess this could be done with SASS in a few lines

Comment: Sorry the question has been closed, I don't believe it is a duplicate. If you could use SASS here is what the code would look like ```$att: #{"div[data-myattr]"};

@for $i from 1 to 10 {

  #{append($att, #{"+ div:last-child:nth-child(#{1 + $i})"})} {
     color: red;
  }

  $att: append($att, #{"+ div[data-myattr]"});
}```

for a maximum of 10 divs

Answer (score 0):

```css
div[data-myattr] + div[data-myattr] + div[data-myattr] + div { color:blue }
```

```html
<div>
    <div data-myattr>1</div>
    <div data-myattr>2</div>
    <div data-myattr>3</div>
    <div>4</div>  <!-- will be blue -->
</div>

<div>
    <div data-myattr>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div data-myattr>3</div>
    <div>4</div>  <!-- will not be blue -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the number of divs is variable, I will edit my question.